TYPO3 Getting values that were set by the constant editor via
I try to get values set in the constant editor from a ActionController.
In my extension, I have defined constant values in the constants.typoscript to make the values available in the constant editor.
menu {
    # cat=menu; label=uid of submenu folder
    submenuId = -1
    # cat=menu; label=entry url
    entryUrl = /
}

search {
    # cat=search; label=navigation entry
    entryId = -1
}


Now I have written an ActionController
I think I have to get the values via $this->configurationManager, but that seems to be null.
I also have seen this question, but that is outdated
With that deprecation note I came up with that:
$backendConfiguration = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ExtensionConfiguration::class)->get('menu');

But that is only working for the value "backend".
Do I miss something?
Best Regards
peni4142

TypoScript for all frontend plugins can be set in the typoscript block:
plugin.tx_[lowercasedextensionname]
See the manual here:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/Extbase/Reference/TypoScriptConfiguration.html#typoscript-configuration
Let's assume your extensionname is my_cool_extension. Then you need to add a typoscript setup file: setup.typoscript
There you can access your constants like this:
plugin.tx_mycoolextension {
    settings {
        menu = {$menu}
    }
}

Now you can access the settings in all controllers and fluid templates of your extension.
In the controller like this:
$this->settings['menu']

And in the fluid templates like this:
{settings.menu}

Check the manual for more options, like passing the settings to a specific frontend plugin.
EDIT:
To get this working, you must of course make your TypoScript available in your Extension. How to do this, is well documented here:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/UsingSetting/AddTypoScriptWithExtensions.html#add-typoscript-in-your-extension

At least in the past there have been some rare extensions using the constants internally, instead of the setup. I'd call it a bad practice and the approach you described as the correct one.

I could not make it work. I tried the extension key with and without underscore. plugin.tx_my_cool_extensionkey/plugin.tx_mycoolextensionkey

It's without the underscores. Did you make your typoscript available like described here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/UsingSetting/AddTypoScriptWithExtensions.html#make-typoscript-available-for-static-includes ?

And you need to clear the cache after modifying TypoScript.

I think there might be a misunderstanding. The mentioned deprecation note in the question is not related to TypoScript, how the code of the extensions settings is parsed could be completely uncommon inside the extension, or it's TypoScript and could be merged with that from the TypoScript records.

Usually the options for extensions settings are defined in the file ext_conf_template.txt and include a very limited sub-set of TypoScript for constants only. The values can be entered in the install-tool in settings -> extensionsettings -> myCoolExtension and are stored in the global configuration file which is config/system/settings.php or in legacy installation public/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php.

legacy installation means that TYPO3 is NOT installed with composer.

In your question you said, that you defined constants in the constants.typoscript. These are located in EXT:your_ext/Configuration/TypoScript/constants.typoscript and not in ext_conf_template.txt. So what are we now talking about? Please update your question, when you are sure what you want to know. ;-)

I retried that, but I still can't get it to work. @Mogens I use the constants.typoscript to provide the option to set the values in the constant editor. I want to read the values set in the constant editor in the action controller.
